# which sensor better to use for slam?

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping, slam-gmapping, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I saw some clips in internet for slam,they used laser range finder or kinect or mono_camera or stereo camera ...

which sensor is better to use for mapping I'm researcher in rescue robot indoor ...

I can't use just the laser scanner because of the environment has half wall(half down or half up and if I use just the laser scanner i can't understand that robot can pass under wall or not ...)

any suggestion about my problem?

Thanks
Hamid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157791/which-sensor-better-to-use-for-slam?/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

LIDAR sensors are so far the most reliable (if expensive) sensor for performing SLAM with mobile robots. Camera-based/Visual SLAM works well in some scenarios but tends to be (much) more brittle generally. You can use a 3D SLAM approach like [ethzasl_icp_mapper](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_icp_mapper?distro=groovy) with a rotating LIDAR or you can combine a (internal) 2D approach like [hector_mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) with a rgb-d sensor and IMU data to perform 3D mapping. That's what we do in [this video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=olGZv05RLHI) and as can be seen, the robot operates autonomously in the Rescue Arena for 20 minutes without running into obstacles like half height roll/pitch ramps.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-04-27**:
how your robot will find out if the space under the wall is higher than its height so it can pass through it?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-28**:
You can create a octomap from RGB-D data and generate a occupancy grid map based on it that contains only cells of a certain height range. If you select the height range to be that of your robot´s geometry (performing some special treatment for the floor), you´ll get a map that shows where your robot can go (which can be used directly in planning algorithms based on occupancy grids).